# How do I redirect devise sign_in path to a configured URL?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

In a rails 3 project with devise, how puts the login page /users/sign_in in the root path.

my application is placed in

URL like: `http://host/my_app`
I am using devise for authentication

when i call the URL, the URL should automatically redirect to

`http://host/my_app/users/sign_in`
but 
my application is forwarding to 
`http://host/users/sign_in`

how to redirect the  devise authentication to `http://host/my_app/users/sign_in`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to change the "login" path, or the path for when they have successfully authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

The [devise docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes) talk about how to update the sign-in and sign-out routes.  You should be able to prepend `my_app` using the same procedure documented.

Answer (score 0):

you can skip default routes, check it out [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]
as :user do
  get 'my_app/users/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  post 'my_app/users/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
  delete 'my_app/users/signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```